# Locate a mouseover element using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate an element (a `h3` tag which only shows up by hovering onto it). After some search, it seems like `ActionChains` in `selenium` is the way to go. The code has two steps: 1: locate the mouseover object and hovering onto it. step 2: locate the new appread h3 tag. So far, Step 1 is fine. But I got `Unable to locate element:` error for Step 2. For to mention, the `appeared` item an `iframe` object. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
### Step 1: locate the mouseover object
each_username_h = review_block_html.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[starts-with(@class, "username")]')
Hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(each_username_h)
Hover.perform()

### Step 2: locate new h3 tag
user_hyper_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//h3[starts-with(@class, "username")]')
```

### Update (solved)

It seems like I need to click the hovered item. Then I also added a dynamic waiting item (thanks to `michael satish`) which makes sure to locate item when it is available.

```
### Step 1: locate the mouseover object
each_username_h = review_block_html.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[starts-with(@class, "username")]')
Hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(each_username_h)
Hover.perform()

### Step 1.5: click the item
each_username_h.click()

### Step 2: locate new h3 tag
user_hyper_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@href, '/members/')]")))
```

Answer (score 1):

check the time it takes for the new h3 tag to be available in DOM after hovering event.

May find_element_by_xpath is fired before the new h3 tag is created, if that the case you may want to dynamically wait for the new h3 tag

Comment: Thanks and I added a dynamic wait statement, which solves the problem partially.